# Generate Email and INSERT INTO on click

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to generate an email with an MS Access form the user has filled out, as well as INSERT INTO during the same action to record the results into a table.

My table has 7 columns:

- ID (autonumber)
- Date Submitted (Date())
- First_Name (Short Text)
- Last_Name (Short Text)
- Email (Short Text)
- Priority (Short Text)
- Error (Long Text)

The code:

```
Private Sub Submit_Ticket_Button_Click()
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim CustomerEmail As String
' prevent 429 error, if outlook is not open
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If

Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oEmailItem
    .To = "alex.e.bristow2.ctr@mail.mil"
    .Subject = "A Trouble Ticket Has Been Submitted"
    .Body = DoCmd.SendObject
    .Display
End With
Set oEmailItem = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub Submit_Ticket_Button_Click1()

    Dim strinsert As String
    strinsert = "INSERT INTO Trouble Tickets (First_Name,Last_Name,Email,Priority,Error)" & _
    "values('" & FirstName.Value & "','" & LastName.Value & "','" & Email.Value & "','" & Priority.Value & "','" & Error.Value & "');"
            
    DoCmd.RunSQL strinsert

End Sub
```

I get

> "compile error, Expected function or variable"

in the first Sub.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be right:

```
.Body = DoCmd.SendObject
```

Body expects a string holding your message body.